# R- Time series plot with events

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have this example dataset (in my real dataset there is 355 observations)

PRDATE is the date of an event EVENTS is the text of the event COUNT is how many people who got tested for COVID that date.

```
      PRDATE = c("2020-04-20", "2020-28-06","2020-12-07","2020-01-08", "2020-16-09") 
      EVENTS = c("Universities start", "School Summer holidays start", "textexample1", "textexample2", "textexample3")  
      COUNTS = c(378128, 61261, 26712, 1278, 1276)  
      df = data.frame(PRDATE, EVENTS, COUNTS)
```

Comment: To give a meaningful answer you should share the data you want to plot and what you are using to make the plots?

Comment: I edit my post and made an example dataframe. Bare in mind I have 355 different  in combinations my real dataset, some of the dates do not have an EVENT but should still appear on the plot. A line should only appear when an EVENT happend. Makes sense? I am new in R, but i think I will use GGPLOT

Comment: Your data shared returns error `Error in data.frame(PRDATE, EVENTS, COUNTS) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 4`

Comment: I fixed the dataframe now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(df,aes(x=PRDATE,y=COUNT,group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_segment(aes(x=PRDATE, xend=PRDATE,y=0, yend=COUNT),lty=2)+
  geom_text(aes(label=EVENTS),angle=45,vjust=-0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(NA,100000))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: when I do this the dates dont appear as dates on the x-axis put instead as 2020, 2040, 2060, 2080.. I dont know why?

Comment: @hansgans You have to format your x-axis adding `scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month',date_labels = '%Y-%m')` let me know how that goes!